# Changing DOM structure of XML file based on ID's in nodes

Tags: mysql, sql-server, regex, xml, wordpress

I am trying to import a XML (Generated by a SQL Database) file to my WordPress page. The issue is that the hlistings tag is pulling in descriptions and other information through an ID and the information isn't nested. It's easier to describe through the code so check below. Any ideas would be great!

EDIT:
It seems that I might be able to do that with a regex search and replace. If that is the only solution, where do I start?

```
    <!--What the structure needs to look like-->
<root>
    <listing>
        <hotel></hotel>
        <description></description>
        <image></image>
        <location></location>
    </listing>
</root>

<!--What the structure looks like now-->
<root>
    <listing>
        <hotel_ID>534</hotel_ID>
        <description_ID>46</description_ID>
        <image_ID>23</image_ID>
        <location_ID>89</location_ID>
    </listing>
    <description>ID 46</description>
    <image> ID 23</image>
    <location> ID 89</location>
    <hotel> ID 534</hotel>
</root>
```